# Como salvar dados no banco de dados através do ajax?

Tags: ajax

estou tentando enviar um formulário do javascript para o meu webservice através do ajax.

A idéia é que: o javascript envie o formulário completo, e no webservice, será salvo no banco de dados através do metodo persist.

A minha professora nos passou esse código, mas nao entendo como ele funciona:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function($){
            $("#gravar").click(function(event){
                //para a submissao em modo normal
                //event.preventDefault(); se fir submit
                var url="http://localhost:8080/sorte/webresources/entidades.cliente";
                //enviando dados usando POST
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", url, true); //true = assincrono

                //para metodos diferentes de get
                //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                        //var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        //para obter a resposta que o web service enviou
                        var saida = xhr.responseText;//não se aplica a metodo 

                        alert(saida);
                    }
                }
                //var data = JSON.stringify({"idCli":"100","nome":"LaraCroft","rg":"100100"});
                  // xhr.send(data);//so recebe parametro se consumir entreada
                  xhr.send();
                });
            });

    </script>
```

Comment: Ao meu ver, esse código não faz sentido, pois já que está utilizando jQuery, poderia muito bem utilizar `$.get` ou `$.ajax` para fazer a requisição ao invés de `XMLHttpRequest`. Recomendo que leia a documentação do jQuery e refaça esse código, pois tem como faz de forma bem mais simples que isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua professora misturou código em JS (JavaScript) puro com o jQuery, uma biblioteca famosa e largamente usada para lidar com as diferenças entre os navegadores, enquanto o profissional pensa apenas na lógica.

Veja que seu código roda no navegador do cliente (pessoa que acessa o site) e apenas lida com o "visual" do seu sistema. Toda a parte de mexer com Banco de Dados é feita em outra linguagem, a qual vc não nos ilustrou aqui. É como se você tivesse 2 camadas (igual a cebola) e vc só nos mostrou a camada de cima.

O XHR (XMLHttpRequest) é o objeto Javascript que lida com Ajax no navegador. Talvez ela esteja tentando lhe ensinar como usá-lo, mas vou tomar a liberdade de reescrever o código usando apenas jQuery para deixar tudo mais limpo. E vou usar ES6 (versão moderna do Javascript), para deixar tudo mais enxuto:

```
$(() => {
    $("#gravar").click(() => {
        $.ajax(
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/sorte/webresources/entidades.cliente",
            data: {
            }
        ).done(() => {
            $("#resultado").text("Deu tudo certo!");
        }).fail((err) => {
            $("#resultado").html("<span>Deu alguma coisa errada: " + err + "</span>");
        });
    });
});
```

Em síntese, o que esse script faz é associar um clique em um botão, que no seu HTML tem o "ID" de gravar, a uma chamada Ajax. O que a camada Ajax faz em essência, é chamar a URL que sua professora mostrou para vocês.

Deve existir um servidor, Tomcat, Apache HTTP, Axis, ou dependendo da linguagem que você use no servidor, que vai pegar essa URL e conseguir saber para qual serviço ele deve mandar os dados. Como fazer isso? Depende exclusivamente de qual linguagem e das tecnologias que esteja usando no servidor, já que cada uma tem n-padrões de fazer isso.

Veja que no código, eu coloquei *data*, um campo vazio. Aqui, nesse data, vc deve explicar para o JS em que campos estão quais valores que vc deve passar para o webservice. Vou dar um exemplo bem simples:

```
data: {
    nomePessoa : $("#nomePessoa").val(),
    idadePessoa : $("#idadePessoa").val()
}
```

Veja que eu usei também o jQuery, da mesma forma que sua professora usou. Vc poderia ter usado JS puro. Só que vc ia ter que saber qual atributo vc deve usar. Cada tipo de campo (textArea, input simples) possui um atributo diferente para pegar o conteúdo. Sem ver seu HTML não dá para saber muito. Usando jQuery facilita um pouco as coisas.

Se vc quiser que eu explique literalmente o que seu código faz, as únicas partes relevantes de mexer estão nessas duas linhas:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({"idCli":"100","nome":"LaraCroft","rg":"100100"});
xhr.send(data);
```

A segunda linha é bem simples. Ela pega seus dados (data) e manda tudo para o servidor (para aquela URL que vc passou acima).

A primeira linha fica o truque a sua professora queria que vcs entendessem: ela pega os dados que vc especificou, e transforma em texto (que em inglês é string), ou seja, ele "textifica" um conjunto de dados Javascript (nesse caso, o pacote que faz isso é do próprio JS e se chama JSON). Ou seja, *JSON.stringify* pega os dados que vc quer mandar, e transforma isso em texto pq a comunicação via web é feita em texto - assim qualquer serviço que você monte no servidor pode ler o conteúdo.

O jQuery é esperto o suficiente para fazer isso automaticamente, por isso você não viu isso no código que fiz.

Agora, dentro do stringify, que fica o pulo do gato:

```
{
 "idCli":"100",
 "nome":"LaraCroft",
 "rg":"100100"
}
```

Vê a semelhança com o código para *data* que havia feito antes? Ela está usando uma notação chama JSON (JS Object Notation) para o JS saber que vc está trabalhando com dados. Existiam diversas formas de descrever dados em JS no passado, história muito velha para contar, daí surgiu o JSON que unificou tudo e se tornou padrão.

Perceba que ela colocou valores fixos como 100 para o campo *idCli*. Você deve saber como está seu HTML, saber os nomes dos campos, e no lugar de 100 vc deve colocar o código JS para pegar esse valor. Pode usar jQuery se quiser.

Agora, tenha em mente 2 coisas:

1. Os nomes dos campos, por exemplo, aqui vc usou *idCli, nome e rg* devem ser bem conhecidos pelo seu serviço Web. Quase certeza que se você colocar uma letra minúscula no lugar errado seu serviço vai dar pau pq ele acha que ID é diferente de id que é diferente de Id.
2. Como seu serviço vai mapear aquela URL acima para o serviço propriamente dito e como ele vai mapear cada parâmetro para cada variável dentro do seu serviço, depende exclusivamente da linguagem de programação e das tecnologias que vc está usando no serviço, mesmo o protocolo "Web Service" sendo "universal".

Esqueci que para pegar os valores de um campo de entrada, a função é .val() e não .text() - essa você usa para lidar mais com o HTML do que com o conteúdo das coisas.

Comment: Show, muito boa explicação. +1 :D

Comment: Cara, sua resposta foi extremamente fantástica, clareou demais muitas coisas que eu não entendia. Perdoe-me por nao mostrar o html e o backend, irei fazer isso atraves desses dois prints: 
html do form: https://ibb.co/i9r5uq
metodo no java que recebe: https://ibb.co/hfZGHA
No caso desse meu metodo do webservice, nao há nenhum parametro pra receber esse json, e portanto está errado, correto?

Suas dicas foram extremamente importantes, porem é um assunto bem confuso pra mim, perdoe-me se deixei algo passar em branco

Comment: no caso desse comando: var data = JSON.stringify({"idCli":"100","nome":"LaraCroft","rg":"100100"});

idCli, nome e rg sao variaveis que eu criei no ajax e deverão ser correspondidas com os atributos do meu webservice (que, como estou usando persist, são os mesmos nomes das colunas no banco de dados)?

Comment: Adaptei meu javascript com o codigo que me ensinou: https://ibb.co/cNvtfV

No data, devo fazer algo tipo:

{
 "idCli":"null",
 "nome":"$("#nome").val();",
 "rg":"$("#RG").val();"
} 

assim?

PS: idCli = null pois é auto increment no banco

Comment: atualização: inseri um " @Produces("application/json")" no meu metodo no WS, é o bastante pra receber o json?

Comment: Produces seria "eu produzo JSON". Para receber seria o @Consumes se não me falha a memória.

Comment: basta vc olhar a função embaixo dessa que você marcou. Cada parâmetro da função possui uma anotação @param para poder mapear o recebido do JSON para a variável adequada no Java.

Comment: Dica de amigo. Não misture a classe que vai ser o Webservice REST com a Facade de persistência - a que tem ou delega a PersistenceUnit, você ganha mais nota, e separa coisas distintas.